# Keydown en jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

Necesito detectar la pulsación de las flechas del teclado y tengo entendido que es con la función keydown, pretendo pulsarlas y mover esa dirreción un cubo diseñado en css, el problema lo tengo a la hora de detectar la tecla pulsada, que no sé cómo.

Comment: Bienvenido, como estás intentando hacerlo? Que haz investigado? Lee [¿como preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes valerte del evento `keydown`, que en `which` te dice que tecla fue presionada. Las flechas son 37, 38, 39, 40, creo que el código explica todo:

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    switch(e.which) {
        case 37: 
          console.log("izquierda");
          break;
        case 38: 
          console.log("arriba");
          break;
        case 39: 
          console.log("derecha");
          break;
        case 40: // down
          console.log("abajo");
          break;
        default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Haz clic aquí primero para darme el foco, luego presiona las flechas</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Como mencionas es con la función `keydown`, con esta función puedes mandar llamar una función anónima la cual recibe un parámetro de evento, ejemplo:

```
$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

con este parametro puedes hacer varias cosas, como por ejemplo detectar que tecla se preciono dependiendo a su codigo de ascii, ejemplo:

```
$('#input').keydown(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
    if(e.keyCode == 37){
    alert ("izquierda");
  }
  if(e.keyCode == 38){
    alert ("arriba");
  }
    if(e.keyCode == 39){
    alert ("derecha");
  }
    if(e.keyCode == 40){
    alert ("abajo");
  }
})
```

En este ejemplo se detectan las cuatro teclas de arriba, abajo, derecha, e izquierda
Lo puedes checar en este enlace [codepen](https://codepen.io/arnolasco/pen/xxgMrEY)